# database connection in MS Access 2007

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

1. How do I connect the two or many forms in database MS Access 2007?
2. When do to click the Add, Edit and Delete buttons, How do gather the record in database Access?
3. To guide in VB.NET or simple example in VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

Use ADO.NET class library to work with VB.NET and use oledb activex data object library for vb 6.0.

[Learn ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937699.aspx)

[Data Access for VB 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83x67by8(VS.80).aspx)